# Exceeding memory issues on server using PHP

Tags: php, memory, out-of-memory, ram

PHP has memory limits set at a global level in the PHP.ini file. I also know that they can be configured at the local level.

Our memory limit for a query is set to 132MB, but we keeping getting errors like this:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 161480704 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in #{removed_file_path}/script.php on line #{line}`

Currently, we are monitoring our systems through an errror log file, that caches errors while users are browsing a page, as well as using `cron`; however, these don't get logged anywhere.

The error can be fixed by changing any calls to `mysql_query` to `mysql_unbuffered_query`, however I need to know where this needs to be changed for all files on the server. If the script is actually not having memory issues, then I don't want to change the code since I want the server to read the results to RAM wherever possible.

We don't want to increase our memory limit in PHP since our host advises us against that.

What can be done to fix the memory issues? We are running on CentOS 6.7.

Comment: ~150+ MB for a single script execution sounds like a lot of memory for a single script execution. What exactly are you doing with all these rows that you need in memory?

Comment: The scripts run a `SELECT *` query from a table we have. The table stores a row with information for every click that links to our site; as you can imagine, we have a lot of rows being returned. I think when the `mysql_query` function gets called, it stores all results in an array in memory.

Comment: Have you tried *not* doing that? Get only the columns you need and only the rows you want. Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, yadda yadda PDO.

Comment: Are you able to break the problem into smaller chunks so that you don't need to do a SELECT * with no LIMIT? You might need to do that anyway if you want your application to scale well.

Comment: I'll take a look at it and report back.